# Find the Keys in a Prolog Pairs List

Tags: lambda, prolog

I currently have a list of (Key,Value) pairs and I want to pull out all the keys to use in another function.

Such that I have a list called

```
PairsList
```

and I want to

```
retractall(map(Key,_).
```

I have tried:

```
retractall(map(PairsList[(Key,_)],_).
```

but that just throws a syntax error.

Any help would be super!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[retractall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=retractall/1) it's a powerful Prolog memory tool, useful for dynamic information managing, but it's important not to abuse of it. In your question, seems irrelevant. If you have a list of pairs (Key,Value) then

- if you can use SWI-Prolog, there is this interesting library([pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pairs.html%27%29%29)).
  Instead of `(A,B)` uses `A-B`, but for the representation change you gain much. With that library, the builtin you would use is [pairs_keys](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=pairs_keys/2)(Pairs, Keys)
- without any library, the function (but it's a relation, *not* a function) is really easy to write in pure Prolog.

  ```
  keys([(Key,_)|Pairs], [Key|Keys]) :- keys(Pairs, Keys).
  keys([], []).
  ```
- I think the best way is using maplist from library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)), and a very simple predicate:

  ```
  keys(Pairs, Keys) :- maplist(key, Pairs, Keys).
  key((K, _), K).
  ```

  note that this way we can reuse the logic abstracting from 'actual' pair representation: just add

  ```
  key(K - _, K).
  ```

  to handle the preferred Prolog way

Answer (score 1):

If you use SWI-Prolog and module(lambda), you can write

```
maplist(\X^Y^(X = (Y,_)), L, L1),
```

For example this code :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).


t(L, L1) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(X = (Y,_)), L, L1).
```

gives

```
?- t([(1,a), (2,b), (3,c)], L).
L = [1,2,3].
```

Comment: beware the efficiency. lambda need still a bit of love, at least when I tested last time, there was no way to make the variable copy optional...

Comment: @chac: similar is true for `maplist/3`! Efficient support in SWI is still awaiting its realization.